# Error when loading DateTimePicker's value from textfile

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker

I have a problem loading the DateTimePicker's value from a textfile.
The following code will save the value to a `.txt` file in `HH:mm:ss` format because I only need the time values, not dates.

When trying to load the values from the `.txt` file I get an error at the following line(s):

**(dtp = DateTimePicker)**

```
dtp371.Value = prop(1)

dtp300.Value = prop(1)
```

and so on...

This is the error:

```
Value of '1/01/0001 17:15:00' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'MinDate' and 'MaxDate'.
Parameter name: Value
```

Why does it add the `1/01/0001` to the value? Only the time is saved in the .txt file.

```
Private Sub DeadlinesOpslaan()
        Dim Opslaan As StreamWriter

        Opslaan = New StreamWriter("Y:\Jordy Steyaert\Routebord data\Packing 10-zone\deadlines.txt", False)

        Opslaan.WriteLine(dtp371.Name & "|" & dtp371.Value.ToString("HH:mm:ss"))
        Opslaan.WriteLine(dtp300.Name & "|" & dtp300.Value.ToString("HH:mm:ss"))
        Opslaan.WriteLine(dtp114.Name & "|" & dtp114.Value.ToString("HH:mm:ss"))
        Opslaan.WriteLine(dtp115.Name & "|" & dtp115.Value.ToString("HH:mm:ss"))
        Opslaan.WriteLine(dtp113.Name & "|" & dtp113.Value.ToString("HH:mm:ss"))

        Opslaan.Flush()
        Opslaan.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub DeadlinesLaden()
        Dim Laden As StreamReader
        Dim prop(5) As String

        If File.Exists("Y:\Jordy Steyaert\Routebord data\Packing 10-zone\deadlines.txt") Then
            Laden = New StreamReader("Y:\Jordy Steyaert\Routebord data\Packing 10-zone\deadlines.txt", False)
            Do Until Laden.EndOfStream
                prop = Laden.ReadLine().Split("|")

                If String.Equals(prop(0), dtp371.Name) Then
                    dtp371.Value = prop(1) ' ERROR HERE
                End If
                If String.Equals(prop(0), dtp300.Name) Then
                    dtp300.Value = prop(1) ' ERROR HERE
                End If
                If String.Equals(prop(0), dtp114.Name) Then
                    dtp114.Value = prop(1) ' ERROR HERE
                End If 
                If String.Equals(prop(0), dtp115.Name) Then
                    dtp115.Value = prop(1) ' ERROR HERE
                End If
                If String.Equals(prop(0), dtp113.Name) Then
                    dtp113.Value = prop(1) ' ERROR HERE
                End If

            Loop
            Laden.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Some words in the code are Dutch but they are not that important.

Comment: A DTP always contains a Date and a Time.  You only save the Time leaving the Date as  `1/01/0001` which is less than the minimum date of `1/1/1753`

Comment: I understand. Is there a way to read the (time)values and ignore the date?

Comment: your code already ignores the date when the user sets a time, so use today for the date when you read the data,  You also need to turn on Option Strict.  `dtp115.Value = prop(1)` is assigning a string to a DateTime type

Comment: I think this will solve the error problem: `dtp371.Value.ToString(DateTime.Today + (" HH:mm:ss"))`